# How do I dynamically check for empty parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parameter called `foo`. I use an API to send a call to an endpoint which, if successful, will then populate `foo` with the relevant payload data. `foo` has many properties, such as:

- title
- forename
- surname
- Abracadabra

What I want to do using jQuery is once all of these properties have been populated, I then want to go through them all and check if these properties are not populated *or* have a length equal to zero. If this is the case then I want to show a class of `errorMesssage` but only for that specific property.

This is the current code that I'm using to display my elements:

```
function createApplicationVerification1(customerData) {
    var customerOne =
        "<div class='row'><strong>Person 1:</strong></div><br />" +
        "<div class='row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Title</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.p1Title) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'>" +
        validateField(customerData.p1Title) +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Forename</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.p1Forename) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.p1Forename) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row errorRow'><div class='col-md-6'> </div><div class='col-md-6 errorMessage'></div></div>" +
        "<div class='row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Surname</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.p1Surname) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.p1Surname) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>DOB</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.p1Dob.substring(0, 10)) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.p1Dob) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class = 'row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Address</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.app1Address) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.app1Address) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class = 'row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Town</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.app1Town) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.app1Town) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class = 'row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Postcode</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.app1Postcode) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.app1Postcode) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class = 'row validation-row'>" +
        "<div class='col-md-6'><span>Country Code</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'><span>" +
        checkIfEmpty(customerData.countryCode) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
        validateField(customerData.countryCode) +
        "</span></div>" +
        "</div>";

    return customerOne;
}
```

Once this data has been populated, I then call a `checkForErrors()` function which is this:

```
function checkForErrors() {
    $(foo.childNodes).each(function () {
        $(foo).filter(function () {
            return $(foo, this).length == 0;
        });
        $(".errorMessage").text("Required Field.");
        $(".errorMessage").css("display", true);
    });
}
```

My thinking behind this is that for each `foo.childNodes` if it matches the filter where the length is equal to 0 then I want it to show the `errorMessage`.

With this I came across 2 issues.

1. childNodes brings up an error and breaks the js.
2. Because the class name is not unique, once I get one property that matches the rule of 0 in length, then it shows an error message for all properties.

The below image is a rough example of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image: expected outcome of validation checking]

Here's what I'm currently getting:
[image: incorrect outcome of what i'm getting]

I'm getting this because of the class for this html element is the same throughout.

How can I achieve the validation check in a better way than having to define each `errorMessage`'s id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your code according to standards.

Dont repeat. Create a function:

```
function createItem(title, value = "") {
  var isValid = validateField(value); //not sure what you have in mind with that function but
  //you should create dom elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
  return "<div class='row validation-row'>" +
         "<div class='col-md-6'><span>" + title + "</span></div>" +
         "<div class='col-md-5' id ='applicantInfo'>" + value + "<span>" +
         "<div class='col-md-1'><span>" +
         (isValid ? "<span>Y</span>" : "<span>X</span>") +
         "</span></div>" +
         "<div>" + (value.length === 0 ? "" : "<span>Required Field.</span>") + "</div>" +
         "</div>";
}
```

call that function with your data.

```
function createApplicationVerification1(customerData) {
   var r = "<div class='row'><strong>Person 1:</strong></div><br />";
   r += createItem('Title', customerData.p1Title);
   r += createItem('Forename', customerData.p1Forename);
   // ...
   return r + "</div>";
}
```

You dont need a checkForErrors at all. Don't iterate over dom nodes just do it while you create your dom nodes.

Comment: I know it says avoid comments like thanks & +1 but this is perfect, thank you for showing me the correct standards, I'm clearly out of touch and I appreciate the link in the comments of the code snippet.